# Tabelas/Conteúdo temporário no banco?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-temporária

### Situação

Estou querendo gerenciar um processo utilizando os recursos que banco de dados
oferecem, como `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

Contudo todo esse processo é temporário, ou seja, eu tenho que gerar tabelas e dados que assim que a conexão se perder ou for encerrada devem ser excluídos do banco.

### Atual

Estou fazendo um `BEGIN;` no banco e gerando todas as tabelas e seus conteúdos, ao final realizo o `ROLLBACK;`

### Dúvida

Teria alguma forma de melhorar isso?

Comment: Você tem um banco/tabela que são normais/permanentes, mas quer fazer operações que devem ser temporárias? Tem algum motivo para isto? Por que não fazer separado?

Comment: @bigown Eu queria criar um banco separado para todo este processo, mas o infra não permitiu, assim para utilizar os recursos de um banco eu teria de usar o atual, mas não devem ficar "vestígios" no mesmo.

Comment: E se só criar tabelas separadas no mesmo banco? Qual é o banco?

Comment: @bigown editei, pondo a tag, sim seriam tabelas temporárias, assim como seus dados. A finalidade de tudo isso é gerar um arquivos. Igual o que o SPED faz, so que no caso o SPED valida este arquivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que a questão é só criar [tabelas temporárias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) para isto. Faz tudo nelas e elas poderão ser descartadas manualmente ou automaticamente no fim da seção/transação. Pode criar assim:

```
CREATE TEMP tabela ON COMMIT DROP //ou pode ser DELETE ROWS se quiser preservar a estrutura
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/Temp.sql).

Não consigo ver uma forma melhor a não ser não usar o banco de dados.

Comment: Humm muito bom, não conhecia, creio que terei de fazer `ON COMMIT DROP`, para não ficar no banco.

Comment: Do [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) "Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or optionally at the end of the current transaction (see ON COMMIT below)."

Answer (score 2):

Como você gera tabelas e dados que são temporários, utilize tabelas temporárias.

### No SQL Server

`CREATE TABLE #tabela_local(
id int,
descricao varchar(50))<br/>
CREATE TABLE ##tabela_global(
id int,
descricao varchar(50))`

Quando você coloca o símbolo # antes do nome, está dizendo que a tabela é temporária. No SQL Server temos dois possíveis escopos para uma tabela temporária: local(#) e global(##). 
**Local:** a tabela estará disponível para aquele usuário e será automaticamente deletada quando o usuário encerrar aquela sessão. 
**Global:** a tabela estará disponível para todos os usuários logados e será deletada quando os usuários que estão referenciando a tabela encerrarem suas sessões. 
Mesmo que as tabelas serão deletadas, você pode fazer um DROP TABLE quando terminar suas operações.

É possível criar tabelas temporárias com outros SGBD como MySQL e Postgres. A sintaxe varia um pouco de acordo com o Banco que está sendo utilizado. Outra coisa que muda é o escopo das tabelas, se não estiver enganado o MySQL só oferece escopo local.

Comment: Antes da sua edição não tinha a tag Postgres então coloquei o exemplo do SQL Server. No Postgres a sintaxe é CREATE  [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } TABLE nomeDaTabela (id integer not null, ...)
Você pode definir se o escopo será global ou local e para dizer que a tabela é temporária informe 'TEMP'

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira de separar usuários e aplicações dentro de uma mesma base é utilizando esquemas:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html

Um esquema é parte da qualificação de um objeto. Quando uma tabela `t` é criada na base `b` o seu nome completo será `b.[esquema].t`:

```
b=> create table t (c text);
CREATE TABLE

b=> \d t
     Table "public.t"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 c      | text | 

b=> select * from b.public.t;
 c 
---
(0 rows)
```

O esquema usado no nome, quando não especificado, é o esquema atual:

```
b=> select current_schema;
 current_schema 
----------------
 public
```

O esquema atual é o primeiro esquema no caminho de busca que exista:

```
b=> show search_path;
   search_path   
-----------------
 "$user", public
```

Se existisse um esquema com o nome do usuário da sessão este seria o esquema atual.

Para fazer com que um esquema seja o esquema atual aponte o caminho de busca para aquele esquema:

```
b=> set search_path to s1;
SET

b=> show search_path;
 search_path 
-------------
 s1
```

Se selecionarmos o esquema atual ele vai voltar nulo porque não existe um esquema s1:

```
b=> select current_schema;
 current_schema 
----------------

(1 row)
```

Para criar o esquema:

```
b=> create schema s1;
CREATE SCHEMA

b=> select current_schema;
 current_schema 
----------------
 s1
```

Agora podemos criar uma tabela `t` no esquema `s1` sem precisar qualificar o esquema:

```
b=> create table t (c text);
CREATE TABLE
```

Como já existia uma tabela `t` no esquema `public` agora são duas. Uma no esquema `public` e a outra no esquema `s1`:

```
b=> \d *.t
     Table "public.t"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 c      | text | 

       Table "s1.t"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 c      | text |
```

Como o esquema atual é `s1` não é necessário qualificar o nome para inserir em `s1.t`:

```
b=> insert into t (c) values ('texto');
INSERT 0 1
b=> select * from t;
   c   
-------
 texto
(1 row)

b=> select * from public.t;
 c 
---
(0 rows)
```

Se o esquema não for mais necessario:

```
b=> drop schema s1 cascade;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to table t
DROP SCHEMA
```

O `cascade` derruba todos os objetos dependentes. Volte para o caminho de busca default:

```
b=> set search_path to "$user", public;
SET
b=> select current_schema;
 current_schema 
----------------
 public
```